# Check iOS version as Apple suggested

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

Apple in the iOS7 transition guide [wrote a snippet to check the iOS version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TransitionGuide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH14-SW1)

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1) {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
}
```

But what if Apple come out with another iOS6 version such as 6.2? automatically the iOS7 version will be loaded.
Would be better something like that:

```
if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) >= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0) {
   // Load resources for iOS 7 or later
} else {
   // Load resources for iOS 6.1 or earlier
}
```

Unfortunately this foundation number is not available. Do you think that Apple suggested method is safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iOS 6.2 should have all of the API features of 6.1, so that will work fine.  These tests are mainly for knowing how to do something (i.e. which API features exist).

Comment: Deprecated API's might be removed though. Perhaps the safest check is using `-respondsToSelector:` to see if a method call is supported? Though this will only work on existing classes that have been changed over the years.

Comment: If you look at the docs you can even see that NSFoundationVersionNumber_IOS_6_0 shares the same number as 6_1 so it's unlikely that 6_2 will have a different number and break anything

Comment: But 5.1 has a greater foundation version number than 5.0. So if 6.2 had a version number greater than 6.1 then the test `floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) <= NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1` would *fail* on 6.2, and 6.2 would be mistaken as 7.0. The fact that *"iOS 6.2 should have all of the API features of 6.1"* does not help.

Comment: We aren't talking about 5.1 we're talking about 6_0 and 6_1 Which do have the same number.

Comment: I've seen also that 6.0 and 6.1 share the same number, and Apple unlikely will release a 6.2, because normally bugfixings come in 6.x.y. The best system for me to understand an iOS versions is pick up a method or a class available to all devices and check for its existance, but since this one is "approved" by Apple I was curios about people opinion on its safety. I'm wondering why Apple don't put a simple +isIOS7 +isIOS6 etc

Comment: @Abizern: My point was only that the version of 6.2 *could be* greater than the version of 6.1, and therefore this answer does not really answer the question. But I agree that there probably will not be a 6.2 which introduces major changes.

Comment: How does this compare to the traditional `[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]`? Pros and cons? Anyone?

Comment: Oh, I see... the foundation version is NOT a human readable string (e.g. `751.32`)...

Answer (score 3):

NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_6_1 == 993.00, there is no problem.
But NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0 == 1047.22 , so floor() function  maybe not right~

Comment: Exactly, you don't need to use floor at all.

Comment: You need the floor in certain cases, e.g.     if (floor(NSFoundationVersionNumber) < NSFoundationVersionNumber_iOS_7_0) The reason is there might be a iOS 7 beta with less than 1047.20, e.g. 1047.10.